# How to use youtube data api in wamp server

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, wampserver

I have downloaded [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and extracted the google folder into the root of wamp server.

For accessing search function of youtube I have used **search.php** from this [github repo](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/php). In order to create API key I have followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).

In step 5 I selected **Public API access** option and in **create new key** window I selected **Browser key** option.

As I am using a localhost system (wamp server), I used this address `http://localhost/` for creating my app. The newly created API key was replaced with REPLACE_ME in the `$DEVELOPER_KEY`  of **search.php**.

I opened the search.php in my local host and searched for keyword *people are awesome* but its showing this error.

```
An client error occurred: HTTP Error: 
  Unable to connect: 'fopen(compress.zlib://https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&amp;q=people+are+awesome&amp;maxResults=25&amp;key=forsecurityreasonsapikeyisremoved) 
  [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: operation failed'
```

**EDITED**

As i am trying to solve my problem, i have searched the url in the warning in a browser (with actual key ) and it showed below error

> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&amp;q=people+are+awesome&amp;maxResults=25&amp;key=forsecurityreasonsapikeyisremoved
> ```

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

it seems youtube api is not working other google products api is working

```
www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Henry+David+Thoreau&amp;filter=free-ebooks&amp;key=forsecurityreasonsapike
```

the above link worked

Answer (score 0):

You could first check that your `php.ini` file has this setting set to on

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Edit your php.ini file using the wampmanager menu links to ensure you are editing the correct php.ini file, like so :

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Comment: allow_url_fopen is on